# Script cache:clear returned with error code 255

Tags: php, composer-php, symfony4

I installed Symfony 4.2 via composer

```
composer create-project Symfony/website-skeleton my-project
```

everything works correctly, then I put the project in gitlab. a friend of mine tried to clone it on its own computer in order to work on the same project, and when he runs `composer install`

he got an error :

> Script cache:clear returned with error code 255

Frankly, I tried everything I can find on the web and Stack Overflow but unfortunately, i didn't succeed.

**Thanks in advance for any help**

Comment: Check this https://github.com/symfony/flex/issues/329, Maybe you can get some idea here.

Comment: As a temporary solution, your friend can run command with --no-scripts parameter, like: composer install  --no-scripts

Comment: @AndriiFilenko as a temporary solution it works. thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First: How I got the error:

1. I have a symfony 4.2 installed application in a folder called my-project
2. I copied the content of the project to another folder called my-App using           CTRL-C then CTRL-V (copy-paste)
3. I put it to my gitlab project
4. My friend cloned the project and run Composer install and He got the Error
   "Script cache:clear returned with error code 255"

Second: How I solved this:

1. Actually, when you make a CTRL-C and CTRL-V to the content of the symfony project folder, **you are not copying everything**, all the .files (dot files example .env, .test, .gitignore) are hidden.
2. in order to copy the other hidden files such as .env you should open your terminal and type "cp .env (to your location)" in my case, it was "cp .env ~/Desktop/newApp"

> **Hint:** in order to display all the folders and files in a folder use "ll" (ll: aliased to "ls -lh") instead of "ls" command.

Comment: this solved it. and now i feel kinda stupid :D

Answer (score 3):

In my case was that I removed some packages that I didn't need from the `composer.json` but I forgot to remove them from `config/bundle.php`.

So check `config/bundle.php` and if you find something there that isn't right, go delete it!

Answer (score 2):

Downgraded temporarily from composer 2 to composer 1. Then I had this error after doing `composer req symfony/orm-pack`.

```
Executing script cache:clear [KO]
 [KO]
Script cache:clear returned with error code 255
[...Stacktrace...]
!!  
Script @auto-scripts was called via post-update-cmd

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

I had to remove `@auto-scripts` from my `composer.json` file. Not sure if this will lead to correct beahvior, but I was just followiing a tutorial.

Turn

```
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ]
```

into

```
        "post-update-cmd": [
            ""
        ]
```

Answer (score 1):

I have this error message  but the problem was with cache being deleted, solve it with

`console cache:warnup`

Answer (score 1):

It happened to me too. Turns out my composer simply did not have enough memory available! Try this (it worked for me):

```
COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1 composer <your-composer-command-here>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had this error message.

I removed the SwiftMailer bundle but not the config swiftMailer.yml file
Symfony was unable to manage this configuration file

I solved this by removing the yml file

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem, in my case when installing symfony version 4 and 5.

Error:

```
Executing script cache:clear [KO]
 [KO]
Script cache:clear returned with error code 255
```

I solved it by downloading composer manually and running composer.phar :

```
php7.1 composer.phar create-project symfony/website-skeleton:"^4.4" symfony4
```

And now I have no problem installing symfony.